# DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime

I need to enter dates and time(input as strings) into my database but there's no change (remains as 0000-00-00 for the date and 00:00:00 for the time). I know I'm supposed to use DateTime::createFromFormat() but I'm not sure how to go about it. Please be patient and explain to me how I'm supposed to go about it and what is happening in each step and if I want to return the date from the database on later on, how will I go about it? I'm using     `$date` and `$starttime` , `$endtime`.

Comment: ok wait... wat do u mean by "there's no change"... can u show us some of your codes so that we can help you....

Comment: I'm confused... You want to store a string that says "on this date, from time A to time B"? Please shows us some code, or explain better what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While inserting, use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert your String date to `Date` or `DATETIME` based on the format as :

```
   INSERT INTO TABLE1(date, startTime, endtime) 
   VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('$date','%d/%m/%Y'),
          STR_TO_DATE('$starttime','%d/%m/%Y a%h:%i:%s'),
          STR_TO_DATE('$endtime','%d/%m/%Y a%h:%i:%s'));
```

Similarly use `DATE_FORMAT` during retrieval to convert into string of desired format as:

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y') AS formatter_date,
         DATE_FORMAT(starttime,'%d/%m/%Y a%h:%i:%s') AS formatted_startTime
         DATE_FORMAT(endtime,'%d/%m/%Y a%h:%i:%s') AS formatted_endTime
  FROM TABLE1;
```

Let me know, if you need further explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Worked perfectly

Comment: @JoannaIrungu: Any question?

Comment: The date part works fine, but the time still reads as 00:00:00 in the database. Also, how can I set a column to always show when a particular row entry was made, that is, the time?

Comment: @JoannaIrungu: 1. Is your columns of datetime type and are you really passing the tie fragment? 2. Are you looking for some audit column? If yes, add a trigger to update the particular column with current time when insert event happens. I you need help in creating triggers, let me know. If you are asking some else, please clarify.

Comment: @JoannaIrungu: Something like this: `CREATE TRIGGER audit_time AFTER INSERT ON TABLE1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     UPDATE TABLE1 SET CREATE_DATE = NOW() WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
  END;`. Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html for more details.